# Django login sends empty username

Tags: django

I am using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` with a form like this at my login template

```
    <form method="post" action="/login/" id="loginform">{% csrf_token %}
        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        <br>
        {{ form.username }}
        <br>
        <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
        <br>
        {{ form.password }}
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/redirect/">
        <input type='button' class='button' value='Sign In'>
    </form>
```

my `urls.py` is something like this:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^redirect/$', redirect)
```

and my view is:

```
def redirect(request):
    logging.debug('user logging in: %s' %request.user.username)
    username = request.user.username
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
[...]
```

the problem is that request username is empty. So I always get an error at `user = User.objects.get(username=username)`

Any ideas how did that happened?

PS: Admin (django contrib admin) login fails with the same reason, too

UPDATE: at my logging file I get this:

`2013-06-17 07:11:01,932 DEBUG request user is: AnonymousUser`

UPDATE 2:

I also paste this from settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'main.common.tz_middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
     'main.common.sslMiddleware.SSLRedirect',
     'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

UPDATE 3: Things are getting more absurd. I substituted the `redirect` function with this:

```
def redirect(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

and it works. So, request object when redirected keeps user info... However this is not the solution

Comment: I am quite sure `action="."` should be `action="login/"`; you should remove the `onclick` attribute and change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. Can you clarify what you mean "admin login fails" - which admin, the django contrib admin?

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggested, but I still get an `AnonymousUser` as the `request.user`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update the question with the code with your changes.

Comment: How is the template being shown to the user? Is it rendered via a view or via the 'template_name' argument that user2492126 referred to in his/her answer?

Comment: yes. At the moment I still use user2492126's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try to put template_name in urls...
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),

And why don't you use django-registration (it works on Django 1.4.5)

Comment: just for trying, maybe you can try to use standart middlewares:
`
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
`